# transpose on PyTorch : IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)

Tags: pytorch, transpose

I want to transpose the data I have using transpose, but I am encountering such an error. My data and related process uploaded to github.

https://github.com/nurkbts/error/blob/main/error.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`torch.bmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html) (*batch matrix multiplication*), both tensors must have three dimensions (first one being the batch). Please read the documentation for the details.

Since you were trying to use `bmm`, you should just use the `@` operator (equivalent to applying [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html?highlight=matmul#torch.matmul)). Also, don't forget to transpose. This will give you a shape `(64, 64)`.

```
_scores = queries@keys.T / np.sqrt(64)
```

Comment: Alternatively, queires = torch.FloatTensor(queries)
keys = torch.FloatTensor(keys)
# Scaled Dot Product
scores = torch.bmm(queries.unsqueeze(0), keys.unsqueeze(0).transpose(1, 2)) / np.sqrt(64)